# Easiest way to merge 2 or more ELF files

Tags: linker, embedded, elf, 68000, coldfire

I'm working on some embedded code for a class project that currently (per requirements) creates a number of srec files and merges them. I'd like to be able to load this code into QEMU, but it is generally only happy with ELF files. What is the esiest way to merge the original ELF files instead of the srecs. 
Also acceptable, a method to convert the srec back into an ELF and have the resulting file be loadable (objcopy seems to produce fairly broken files doing this (no architecture amoung others). 
The tools must be capable of working with m68k binaries, but the host system is plain x86.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the easiest solution to my original problem was actually to add SREC loading to qemu. I am already modifying the source to add board support, so SREC support isn't much additional work. I found some code on github from someone who had already done so and used it as a basis for my work.

https://github.com/MegabytePhreak/qemu-mcf5307/commit/d3bceb911893b37b2524d6e804bac96691d4d33c

Comment: Seems to be an answer to the "problem", but not to the question ... at least not as asked in the title.

Answer (score 4):

Easy...
let's assume : a.c and b.c

```
gcc a.c -c -o a.o
gcc b.c -c -o b.o
ld -r a.o b.oc -o c.o
```

c.o now containes both a.o and b.o as a relocatable ELF file.

--Ivan

Answer (score 2):

Please look at [ELFIO library](http://sourceforge.net/projects/elfio/). It contains WriteObj and Writer examples. By using the library, you will be able to create ELF binary files on different host platforms.

Answer (score 0):

Use your linker perhaps?

An srec file contains only the linked/located loadable binary, an elf file contains additional meta-data that is lost in the generation of the binary, so reversing back to elf may not be possible, especially if the elf needs to be relocatable.